# is the grade behind new retaining wall ok?

Tags: retaining-wall

Had a 60 year old stone and mortar wall replaced with a new modern stone wall. Hired a local company to do it and it looks good but it's considerably shorter than I thought it was going to be. Is the grade behind the wall a problem, or is it ok?

Old wall:
[image: oldwall1]

[image: oldwall2]

New wall:
[image: newwall1]

[image: newwall2]

[image]